# Can a charge smaller than that of an electron exist? If so how?

Tags: electrons

In school I've always been taught that the smallest charge possible is that of an electron( or proton) however I recently solved a question regarding a dipole and the charge came smaller than that of a proton, after  the solution given in the book however, there was a little statement written saying this can also exist in real life as well which seems off to me.. like how can you get less charge then the smallest unit of charge? If the answer is quarks well don't they exist in a combined state and wouldnt they combine to form protons and stuff (don't know too much about this topic tho.. I know a little thru YouTube videos but that's it) and hence change the charge to a multiple of that of a proton? Any insight is welcome

*Please note that this is not a homework question, it's just out of my curiosity.. thx for understanding!
Also not rly sure if I should ask this on chem stack exchange or phy..

Comment: Forget quarks, it is much simpler than that. See, if I work for some company part-time, say 1 day a week, they can claim that they hired 0.2 of a person...

Comment: It's pretty weird that a quark should have a fractional charge, once you get used to the idea of an electron having unit charge. But if we'd discovered quarks first, then the charge of an electron might be regarded as -3 (I leave it to the physicists to correct me).

Comment: As for the dipole, those aren't "real" partial charges (fractions of electrons or protons, say), it's a symbolic representation, as Ivan suggests not translatable into tangible objects.

Comment: @Dp03, Don't forget to do a dimensional analysis of dipole moment and charge. What was the exact problem?

Comment: @M. Farooq, it was a basic problem and I was able to do the calculation easily but what intrigued me was the last line of the solution which I mentioned above.. I'd also like to thank Ivan ,Buck and M. Farooq for ur comments, now getting back the question was-

Comment: HCL molecule which had a dipole moment of 3.4 * 10^-30 Cm, distance between them was given as 1.0 * 10^-10 m, my answer came to be 3.4 * 10^-20 C ( it was given that we can assume the charges to be equal and opposite).

Comment: I think Buckthorn has answered it well. I think it is historical that electrons were discovered first.

Answer (score 1):

Dipole moments have a distance times an implicit charge, but you could give the moment as unit charge separation times a distance which is not the bond length. This would eliminate fractional charges and suggest some distance, which suggests that an electron and the nucleus are point charges separated by something less than the bond length. This is difficult to visualize. The electron is not really a point charge. Dipole moment is not separable into fractional charges or tiny distances, it measures a distortion of charge.

And when you think about it, an undistorted charge distribution (like electron density in benzene) is still "distorted" in that electron density is between atoms and above/below the atomic plane.

Other fractional charges might be imagined in compounds like magnetite: $\ce{Fe3O4}$. Each iron has a charge of $\pu{2.666}$. But if you describe magnetite as $\ce{Fe2O3.FeO}$, then two thirds of the iron atoms have a charge of +3, and one third have a charge of +2. More satisfying.

And then there is cyclopentadienyl anion:

[image]

where each carbon has an extra 0.2 extra electronic charge, and there are other ions like cycloheptatrienyl cation, cyclopropenium cation, etc. that have a surplus or deficiency of electrons.

But there is no fractional electric charge, just fractional molecules, or combined valences. Although, I still wonder how quarks can have a partial charge!